# Can I undo the encryption on my Samsung Ace Style?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, encryption

I want to keep my info private, but I don't want to mess up accessibility or have trouble answering my phone when I'm driving.

Can I undo the phone encryption after I have applied it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see connection between data encryption and accessibility/trouble answering your phone. While the question is valid, could you expand the reason? Was it due to additional security layer that complicate unlocking phone? I'm afraid this might be an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't decrypt an encrypted device. You can only remove the encryption by doing a factory reset.